# Deep Q Pong Learning Failing

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I recently started researching Deep Q learning and have run into issues. Following along with articles on the web (including this one: https://keon.io/deep-q-learning/), I attempted to modify the cart pole example to work with the Pong game. However, even though my solution seems to follow other's (minimize the state, keep differences, etc), the ai literally never gets better (upwards of 800 games one time).

Base Code

```
import numpy as np
from ddqn import DQNAgent
import gym
from PIL import Image
env = gym.make('Pong-v0')
state_size = 88*80
action_size = env.action_space.n
agent = DQNAgent(state_size, action_size)
done = False
batch_size = 32
for e in range(EPISODES):
    state = env.reset()
    prev_state = state
    total_reward = 0
    for time in range(500000):
        env.render()
        current_state_diff = minimize_state(state) - minimize_state(prev_state)
        action = agent.act(current_state_diff)
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        total_reward += reward
        next_state_diff = minimize_state(next_state) -         minimize_state(state)
        agent.remember(current_state_diff, action, reward, next_state_diff, done)
        state = next_state
        if done:
            agent.update_target_model()
            print("episode: {}/{}, score: {}, e: {:.2}"
                  .format(e, EPISODES, total_reward, agent.epsilon))
            break
        if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
            agent.replay(batch_size)
    if e % 10 == 0:
        agent.save("./save/pong-v0-ddqn.h5")
```

Where the minimization function is

```
def minimize_state(state):
    img = Image.fromarray(state)
    state = np.array(img.convert("L"))
    state = state[34:]
    state = state[::2,::2]
    return np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
```

And the DQNAgent is from: https://github.com/keon/deep-q-learning

What's going wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to train it correctly?

Comment: Sadly no. Tried a bunch of things but it never learned properly.

Comment: This is why learning machine learning sucks